# Questions about matrix rank, trace, and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, trace, matrix-rank

> (a) Prove that a square matrix $T$ of rank one has $\text{tr}(T)=0$ if and only if $T^2=0$.
>
> (b) Consider a matrix $A$ of the form $A=aI+T$, where $a\ne0$, $I$ is the identity matrix,
>   and $T$ has rank one and zero trace. Find the inverse and the determinant of $A$.
>
> (c) Find the inverse of $A$ as above when $T$ has rank one but nonzero trace $\text{tr}(T)=b$.
>
> For which value of $b$ is $A$ not invertible?

I'm still stuck on part (a), but campus buildings are closing soon, so I'll be working from home but would love to get some hints / comments on this question.  I'll have limited access to this site - on my phone.

For part (a), I've been trying to look at the SVD of matrix $A$, since one can read off the rank very easily - by looking at the number of non-zero singular values of $A$.  Then I am trying some block matrix multiplication to see whether $T^2 = 0$, from assuming that $\text{tr}(T) =0$.  So far, no luck.  Do you think I should stick with this SVD approach, or is it better to play around with the definition and properties of nilpotent operators?

Any other hints for the other parts of the question would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: hint: if $A$ is rank one, then $A = ab^T$ for some nonzero vectors  $a, b.$ we went over this last year!

Comment: Yes, we did, @abel :) Not sure how this decomposition of A, along with trace =0, can help me conclude that T^2 = 0, though.  I've tried for awhile last night and will try again now.  Can I get another hint perhaps? Thanks...

Comment: let us stick to $n = 2.$ pick any two nonzero vectors $a$ and $b$. form the  rank one matrix $ab^T.$ come back and tell me what you get for the trace of that matrix in terms of the vectors you chose.

Comment: ...I got trace = 1, if I let u= (1,0), and $v^t=(1,0)^T$.  If I scale by $\sigma_1$, then the trace is $\sigma_1$ ...

Comment: try another pair and see how the trace relates to the two vectors you picked.

Comment: hmm...I used u= (3,0), and $v^t=(3,0)^T$.  This gives trace = 9, the product of the first entry of the two vectors.  If I scale by $\sigma_1$, then the trace is $\sigma_1$9 ... (and this also gives a rank one matrix)

Comment: can you also compute the dot products of the pairs you choose and the trace of the rank one matrix. pick generic vectors not special one like you have been doing.

Comment: Oo...hmmm...I got that trace = dot product of the two vectors that form the rank one matrix :) (I picked (2,1), and $(4,2)^T$)

Comment: making progress here. now how should you choose the vector if you want trace to be zero. for these rank one matrices, compute the square too. see what happens.

Comment: I should have vectors of the form u=(x,y), $v=(-x,y)^T$ (or $v=(x,-y)^T$).  and $uv^T$ still forms a rank one matrix T, with trace = 0, and I see now that $T^2$ = 0, too :).

Comment: your $v$ is not right. you don't know how to compute the dot product?

Comment: oops, i meant to swap the coordinates - typo :(  so u=(x,y) and $v=(-y,x)^T$

Comment: How can I conclude the proof?  I feel like I still have to say something more...(before proving the converse), since, so far, everything I've done to verify the statement that I needed to prove...have been done just by inspection/ trial-and-error.  I mean, does a rank one matrix with zero trace *always* have two vectors of the forms stated above -and can't be of any other forms, in order to have the square of the matrix equal to zero?

Comment: i.e., is this a theorem? (that we sort of verified..)

Comment: ah, I think I got it now :)  thanks so much for the help @abel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(a) If $T$ is rank one, $T$ should be of the form $T=\sigma_1 uv^T$ where $\sigma_1$ is the highest singular value and $u$,$v$ are left and right singular vectors respectively. Convince yourself that this is true using singular value decomposition. You might need the cyclic property of trace as well.

Hover mouse pointer over the shaded area to see more

> $$0=trace(T)=trace(\sigma_1uv^T)=\sigma_1v^Tu$$

and even more

> $$T^2=\sigma_1^2uv^Tuv^T=\sigma_1^2uv^T(v^Tu)$$

(b) Use the fact that $A=aI+\sigma_1 uv^T$. Observe what happens when $T$ is rank-one and zero-trace. Now say $B=\alpha I+\beta uv^T$ for some unknown constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Try to find if there are any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $AB=I$ and $BA=I$. If you are still struggling, take a look at sherman-morrison formula.

(c) use the same strategy as in (b).

Comment: By trial-and-error (see above), I was able to see that, with specific choice of vectors that form a rank one matrix with zero trace, the square of the matrix is equal to zero, @dineshdileep.  Last night, I spent quite a bit of time on the SVD of T, and I do accept that it is of the form $\sigma_1 uv^T$.  How could I proceed from this angle(compared to my work above)?How could I use trace = 0 now, from the SVD of T?  My guess would be to look at the similarity transforms, since trace(T) is invariant under such transforms.  What do you think?  Or, go a different route to concluding that $T^2$=0?

Comment: And I read up on the cyclic property and linear property of trace, too - but not sure how I could use either one of these properties...thanks, @dineshdileep

Comment: I actually got it now, multiplying T^2 out and moving some parts around that are scalars after matrix multiplication :) Thanks again @dineshdileep ...

Comment: Thanks so much for your edited answer for part(a) - that's exactly what I did, @dineshdileep :).  I'm working on part(b) now, and am using the Sherman-Morrison formula.  But I feel that this is very...specialized and doesn't really reinforce any of the core linear algebra that an old exam should be testing.  What do you think?  Is there a more "fundamental" way to solve this problem, i.e. , find the inverse (and then the determinant) of an invertible matrix that has been perturbed or "corrected" by a rank-one marix?  Thanks...

Comment: did you try finding $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: I've been trying for awhile @dineshdileep but I seem to be going in circles and not able to find an "a" and a "b"...so I'll move on for now.  (When I go to solve for a or b, I seem to get an (aI + T)^-1 term, which is what I'm trying to find.) Feel free to comment further if you have another tip you'd like to share.  Thanks again :)